# A word to refer to both physical objects and conceptual ideas

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

If I am referring to a number of concrete objects I can use multiple terms such as bodies, objects, things, etc.

If I am referring to a number of abstract concepts I can also use many terms such as ideas, concepts, principles...

Is there a noun that represents a step higher in the taxonomic hierarchy to represent both abstract and concrete *things*?

Comment: how about "nouns"

Comment: @Kevin Not a bad suggestion, but I am not looking for a part of speech.

Comment: You have a few answers to get you started, but we're really trying to avoid using this site for "single word requests." If you have a particularly *interesting* problem to solve, all we ask is that you put a research effort into the question. See: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests/1737#1737 or http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity

Comment: @RobertCartaino I personally think that this *is* an interesting problem, and at least the three respondents did as well. My question was not asked as a 'single sentence' and has multiple avenues for discussion. It is also not easily googled. I believe this makes it a fair question. I would agree that this site should not be a dictionary for the lazy, but I do not think this falls into that category... But then I am not a moderator. Regards.

Comment: Reopened. Let's see how it goes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Noun* is just the grammatical equivalent of ***Entity***, and that term might suit, depending on what you need it for. This is what Frawley says, in *Linguistic Semantics*, Lawrence Erlbaum 1992, p xvii, 533. [A college text in semantics; the class comes after [Intro Ling](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/210.html) -jl]

> From Chapter 3, "Entities", pp 62-63.  [Chapter 3 deals with nouns.
>     Chapter 4, "Events", deals with verbs, using much the same analyses. -jl]
>
> 3.11 Nouns and Entities: Formal and Notional Definitions.
>
> "Any student reared in the Western grammatical tradition will say
>       that a noun is the name of a person, place, or thing and thus define
>       a noun by its semantic representation.  Two observations conspire to
>       weed this view out of our untutored beliefs about language.  First,
>       there are many things that are nouns but not exactly persons,
>       places, or things. 'Smoothness' is a noun, but it does not readily
>       appear to represent a thing.
>
> "Second, a noun is not a *notional class*, something defined by its
>       *conceptual content*, but a *form class*, something defined by its
>       *structural* or *formal* properties (Lyons 1966, 1968).  Formally, a
>       noun is identifiable because of what other categories and forms
>       *co-occur* with it.  Under this view, a noun is something that can
>       be a subject (that which controls agreement with a verb) or
>       something that takes certain modifiers, like a definite article. By
>       these criteria, 'smoothness' is a noun, in spite of the variation in
>       its notional content, because it co-occurs with the definite
>       article: 'the smoothness of the wood'.
>
> ...
>
> "But curiously, when the traditional notional definition ("A noun is
>       the name of a person, place, or thing") is reversed, the definition
>       turns out to be true.  Nouns are not always persons, places, or
>       things, but persons, places, and things *always turn out to be
>       nouns!*
>
> "Nouns *do have* purely formal properties because at the grammatical
>       level they are contentlessly manipulated by syntax, just like any
>       other category, but these formal properties are supported by
>       overwhelmingly consistent semantic factors. Nouns incontrovertibly
>       tend to encode *entities*, broadly construed."

- Study guide [here](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/meta4/frawleyq.pdf)
- Properties of Entities [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/meta4/FrawleyEntities.pdf)

Comment: Upvoted both this and the answer that suggests "things" because I think they both work. "Entity" is just a higher-register equivalent of "thing"; in formal/academic writing I would hesitate to use "thing", and "entity" would probably be the best bet.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I meant at the beginning by "depending on what you need it for". Context is everything for vocabulary choice.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, although the word (to me at least) evokes the notion of a physical embodiment. Am I alone in this 'familiar' understanding?

Comment: @ach: Not really; see Dictionary.com's definition of *[entity](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/entity)*: "something that has a real existence".  Now we're down to defining *existence*.  Physical existence or theoretical existence?

Comment: @ach: I think there are two readings to 'entity' one where it has 'physical embodiment, but also one that refers to really any instance of a coherent concept, like the number 7 (that is, 7 is an entity of sorts).

Comment: @Mitch Thank you. I like this line of thinking, that an entity can represent the 'embodiment' of a concept - almost a wrapper.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the last word of your question, I am becoming increasingly sure that [*thing*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/thing) may be the closest single-word fit you will find for this definition.  While it is generally applied to the material world, it *can* be applied to the conceptual as well, giving it a broader scope than terms such as *object* (solely material) and *concept* (solely abstract).

Comment: I agree somewhat that 'thing' is abstract enough to represent both; however I feel that it lacks formality.

Answer (score 0):

*[Ephemera](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ephemera)*, "transitory things", which is all things.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, though I am not certain if the adjective 'transitory' actually does apply to all things. Abstract concepts (and concrete objects like the universe for that matter) often exist without the inherent notion of a time span.